# Testing text for links

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, model-view-controller

**update**

I have a regular expression inside a resource file, it is rendered through a @Action method which takes all resource strings and outputs a script with them:

```
@model IEnumerable<LocalizationModel>
; (function (window) {
    var l = {
    @foreach(LocalizationModel file in Model)
    {
        @:@file.Title: {
        foreach(var entry in file.Items)
        {
            @:@entry.Key: @Html.Raw(@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(entry.Value.ToString(), true)),
        }
        @:},
    }
    };

    // expose the l object to the global namespace.
    window._l = l;
})(window);
```

This partial is in turn minified:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ContentResult Localization()
    {
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // easily replaceable by user culture.
        IEnumerable<LocalizationModel> model = GetLocalizationModel(culture);

        const string viewPath = "Localization";
        string view = RenderPartialToString(viewPath, model);
        string minified = JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(view, false);

        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = minified,
            ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            ContentType = Constants.JavaScriptContentType
        };
    }
```

This produces a result similar to this (beautified):

```
(function (b) {
    var a = {
        Common: {
            Errors: "Errores",
            SingleError: "Error",
        },
        Regex: {
            WebLink: '(?i)\\b((?:https?://|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+|\\(([^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+|(\\([^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+|(\\([^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:\u0027".,\u003c\u003e?«»“”‘’]))',
            Link: '(?i)\\b((?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+|\\(([^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+|(\\([^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+|(\\([^\\s()\u003c\u003e]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:\u0027".,\u003c\u003e?«»“”‘’]))',
        },
    };
    b._l = a })(window);
```

Then, somewhere, I do:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(_l.Regex.WebLink);
console.log(pattern.test(input.val()));
```

But I get an "invalid quantifier" error when creating the RegExp.

What is wrong?
I'm now thinking the unicode characters might be the breaking difference here?

Comment: Here's a clue... `/_l.Regex.Link/.test("_l.Regex.Link") // true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `_l.Regex.Link` and `_l.Regex.WebLink` are, but you're testing for a regex pattern that's literally "_l.Regex.Link", not the variable. If they are already RegExp objects, just remove the `/`s, if they're strings create the RegExp objects first:

```
var pattern = new RegExp( _l.Regex.Link );
console.log( pattern.test( p ) );
```

Comment: when I try to create a RegExp object like this with the provided expression, it yields "SyntaxError: invalid quantifier"

Comment: You'll have to show your full code. There's an error in the regex string.

Comment: The `(?i)` at the start seems to be the culprit. Removing it makes the regex work. I'm not sure what its function is supposed to be, possibly an `i` modifier?

Comment: You seem to be right, now all I need to do is figure out a way to add the `i` modifier.

Comment: You can add it as the second parameter when you create the RegExp object.